# UINavigation controller UIViewController and UItoolbar as a subview issue

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, subview, uitoolbar

Hey guys i am trying to leave the augmented reality and go to the next view controller of to my navigation controller

the code is from ARKit demo  and i just added programmatically a UIToolbar as a subview which has an action button ..I want this button to lead to the next view controller of my existing navigation controller. the action takePicture: is executed as i have an NSLog message but the new viewcontroller is not added

this is the code of the ARGeoViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "ARViewController.h"
#import "AfterARViewController.h"


@interface ARGeoViewController : ARViewController {
CLLocation *centerLocation;
AfterARViewController *afterARViewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *centerLocation;
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AfterARViewController *afterARViewController;

@end
```

this is the code of the ARGeoViewController.m

```
#import "ARGeoViewController.h"

#import "ARGeoCoordinate.h"
#import "ARViewController.h"

@implementation ARGeoViewController

@synthesize centerLocation;

@synthesize afterARViewController;


- (void)setCenterLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation {
[centerLocation release];
centerLocation = [newLocation retain];

for (ARGeoCoordinate *geoLocation in self.coordinates) {
    if ([geoLocation isKindOfClass:[ARGeoCoordinate class]]) {
        [geoLocation calibrateUsingOrigin:centerLocation];

        if (geoLocation.radialDistance > self.maximumScaleDistance) {
            self.maximumScaleDistance = geoLocation.radialDistance;
        }
    }
}

 }
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;


// create a bordered style button with custom title
UIBarButtonItem *playItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
                                                                           target:self
                                                                           action:@selector(takePicture:)] autorelease];


NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                  playItem,
                  nil];
toolbar.items = items;

// size up the toolbar and set its frame
// please not that it will work only for views without Navigation toolbars. 
[toolbar sizeToFit];
CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;
CGRect mainViewBounds = self.view.bounds;
[toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(mainViewBounds),
                             CGRectGetMinY(mainViewBounds) + CGRectGetHeight(mainViewBounds) - (toolbarHeight),
                             CGRectGetWidth(mainViewBounds),
                             toolbarHeight)];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];


}

 - (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender
 {
NSLog(@"takepicture");
if(self.afterARViewController == nil)
{
    AfterARViewController *afterARController = [[AfterARViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithNibName:@"AfterARViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.afterARViewController = afterARController;
    [afterARController release];
    [cameraController release];


}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.afterARViewController  animated:YES];

    }


  @end
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with ARKit, but is cameraController part of the navigation controller's stack? By releasing it when you do you might be throwing things off.   Just as a test, try commenting out the line of code that releases cameraController to see if it's impacting this.

Also, FWIW I would have expected the code that your using to set up the toolbar to be in viewDidLoad, not viewDidAppear.